# Custom text format and cell overflow

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use a custom number format (without the quotes), the problem being with the text part:

```
"...;...;...;@* "
```

When I format text with this format and when it's simply "@" or "@_)" it works fine. But when I make it "@* " to make it left-aligned it stops overflowing and displays ### instead. What can be done to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, but have no authority to cite for it, just logic, that it is due to what you are asking Excel to do.

When using the fill approach on a cell with few enough characters that it is not filled by the entry itself, Excel can easily then add enough of the fill character to fill the cell.

Note that in this case it will not spill over, either with fill or without, because there are not enough characters to fill the width and still need more room to display.

If you fill a cell with MORE characters than can fit, Excel knows to fill the cell with what it can display and allows it to "run over" blank (true null) cells to the right. Enter something in one of the cells it is spilling into (or "the one" if just spilling over into a single neighbor) and Excel faithfully still fills the cell completely, even showing a partial character if one falls partway in the cell and partway into needing to spill over into a neighbor. But it no long runs over (except in a **VERY** unusual case I could expound upon but that is not relevant here since I believe it to be a bug).

However, while that is all meaningful to Excel and therefore computable and displayable, once you lard on the idea "fill" with the `*`  Excel now has to resolve how to solve a contradiction:  you formatted it 1) To fit the cell width exactly, adding characters (space in this case) until it reaches the full width of the cell AND 2) To add as many characters as needed to to do.

Well, it needs a negative number of characters to do so. It seems it fails at that idea and likely, the actual programmed trigger for the, um, beloved `#######` display is failure at achieving an acceptable display in the manner it has been ordered to do.

Note also that this does NOT NOT NOT occur simply from formatting for left alignment. General horizontal formatted cells do the same thing with an entry long enough to ordinarily run over. And cells that would not run over do not with this format whether the horizontal alignment is changed or left at General.

Hence I believe it is due solely to not being able to resolve adding a negative number of (space) characters and that failure to find an acceptable display to send to the monitor (or printer or...) triggers the `#######` display.

Comment: Seems like a good explanation, although it would be more logical for Excel to reason like this: if the text is already longer than the cell (so the number of extra characters is negative) then do not add any extra characters. The result being an overflowing but not left-aligned text. This logic in my view would be more natural.